# web-proxy dead but pid file exists

Tags: cloud, openshift-origin

When trying to set up a node to be used with OpenShift Origin, trying to start the service openshift-node-web-proxy I get the following error that the web-proxy died:

```
# service openshift-node-web-proxy start
web-proxy dead but pid file exists
Starting node-web-proxy: /opt/rh/nodejs010//enable: line 5: scl_source: No such file or directory
```

And by checking the status of the service I get:

```
# service openshift-node-web-proxy status
web-proxy dead but pid file exists
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me to get it working was to run:

```
yum clean all
yum -y update
```

And after that I could already start the service without any errors

The output of yum -y update for me looked like this:

```
# yum -y update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                            |  28 kB     00:00     
 * base: centos.copahost.com
 * epel: be.mirror.eurid.eu
 * extras: centos.bio.lmu.de
 * updates: centos.bio.lmu.de
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
base/primary_db                                          | 4.4 MB     00:00     
epel                                                     | 4.4 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                          | 6.3 MB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.3 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                        |  19 kB     00:00     
openshift-origin                                         | 2.9 kB     00:00     
openshift-origin/primary_db                              |  44 kB     00:00     
openshift-origin-deps                                    | 2.9 kB     00:00     
openshift-origin-deps/primary_db                         | 481 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                       | 5.4 MB     00:00     
vmware-tools-collection                                  |  951 B     00:00     
vmware-tools-collection/primary                          |  18 kB     00:00     
vmware-tools-collection                                                   40/40
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package scl-utils.x86_64 0:20120927-8.el6 will be updated
---> Package scl-utils.x86_64 0:20120927-9.el6oso will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package       Arch       Version               Repository                 Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 scl-utils     x86_64     20120927-9.el6oso     openshift-origin-deps      16 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Upgrade       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 16 k
Downloading Packages:
scl-utils-20120927-9.el6oso.x86_64.rpm                   |  16 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Updating   : scl-utils-20120927-9.el6oso.x86_64                           1/2 
  Cleanup    : scl-utils-20120927-8.el6.x86_64                              2/2 
  Verifying  : scl-utils-20120927-9.el6oso.x86_64                           1/2 
  Verifying  : scl-utils-20120927-8.el6.x86_64                              2/2 

Updated:
  scl-utils.x86_64 0:20120927-9.el6oso                                          

Complete!
```

So if after performing the clean and update you still can't run the service, you could maybe try installing:

```
scl-utils.x86_64 0:20120927-9.el6oso
```

Or someone else reported on another site that he needed to install the following package to get it working:

```
yum -y install scl-utils-20120927-9.el6oso.x86_64
```

If you can't update or install successfully, maybe you need to check whether you have the repository settings fine, they were listed in the beginning of the OpenShift Origin Comprehensive Deployment Guide.

```
http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_comprehensive.html
```

Comment: So, are you saying that this issue is caused by an outdated or missing `scl-utils` package? If yes, please make this more clear.

Comment: @SvW I'm not stating that directly. I'm just providing it in the form of a solution to this problem. So in a way the logical outcome of this would be what you said I believe. However I'm not stating it, because I don't know whether it hadn't been caused by something else that might have been affected by the update of the scl-utils package afterwards.